# can't pick a different account on Pokémon go

Tags: pokemon-go

My daughter signed into her Pokémon go account on my phone...I've tried going into the settings and logging out of hers but when I try to sign back in it just automatically signs into her account. It used to let me pick an account to sign in with but it just skips that part now. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I also have had the same problem. For me I could get around it by signing out, click the sign in, which will automatically sign in the old account and then immediately go sign out again.

After signing out for the second time I was able to choose a different account to sign into.

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it is by going to the settings of the device itself(mine is android).

1. Go to where there's a list of accounts registered to the phone.
2. Remove the google account.
3. Go back into the game.
4. Now it will ask to enter an existing or new Google email account.
5. Choose existing and change to the email account you already have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an Android, you can blow away the stored log-ins by navigating to the app's entry in App Setting and clearing its data.

Go to Settings, scroll down and select Apps, page right to "All," scroll down to Pokemon Go and select it, and hit "clear data."

This will not uninstall the app, and your player data is stored server-side and will remain undisturbed.

After launching the game again, you'll be freshly prompted for a log-in.